# При отправке библиотеки в MavenCenter не возможно прочитать секретный ключ PGP

Tags: android, maven, gradle, gpg

Объясню свои шаги

Создал ключ
gpg --full-gen-key

отправил свой публичный ключ на сервер

```
gpg --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --send-keys 1111111
```

Взял свой приватный ключ

```
 gpg --armor --export-secret-keys my@gmail.com > secring.kbx
```

мой local.properties

```
signing.keyId=11111111
signing.password=USERNAME
signing.secretKeyRingFile=../secring.kbx
```

публикую

```
gradle myLib:publishReleaseAarPublicationToMavencentralRepository
```

получаю ошибку

```
> Unable to read secret key from file: C:\Users\Android dev\AndroidStudioProjects\TestLib\secring.kbx (it may not be a PGP secret key ring)
```

Что я делаю не так никак не пойму

Comment: Укажите что за плагин используете для подписи.

Comment: Скачал доя win  gpg4win-4.0.0 в коде такие строки  apply plugin: 'signing'

Comment: Документация по плагину изучили? https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/signing_plugin.html

Comment: Видимо использую GnuPG

Comment: https://gpg4win.org/thanks-for-download.html

Comment: Если вы ещё здесь) прочитав про плагины решил попробовать с нуля провести все операции, и эта ошибка пропала, но появилась другая

Comment: > Failed to publish publication 'releaseAar' to repository 'mavencentral'
   > Could not PUT 'https://s01.oss.sonatype.org/service/local/staging/deploy/maven2/com/io/coni/testLib1/1.0.1-beta/testLib1-1.0.1-beta.aar'. Received status code 400 from server: Bad Request

Comment: Скорее всего вы пытаетесь залить уже там существующий артефакт. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52825374/5479247